Windows Server 2019 Essentials Error Code 0xc0000185
I have been dealing with an issue with Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Essential. A fresh install an losing all the files etc. on the drive is not preferred.
As a summary, the server became unusable and would blue-screen into a "Critical Process Died" error. When reaching the windows boot menu, the error code (0xc0000185) was displayed, and when trying to run in safe mode the PC would just not boot at all, or return to the same blue screen mentioned above.
I then tried repairing the installation via a bootable USB. This unfortunately did not help. I tried and successfully ran the following commands:
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd

As mentioned above. None of these commands worked.
After this I removed the SSD from the server and inserted it into my laptop to try continue debugging. If booting from the server drive, instead of my original laptop drive, the error is still present. This rules out any hardware issues on the server (I believe).
Once setup on my laptop (Original drive C and server drive D), I tried to some tests on the drive from command prompt:
chkdsk D: /f /r

This returned some bad clusters, but they were replaced and ultimately the test eventually passed. I then tried to run sfc scannow:
sfc /scannow /offwindir=d:\windows /offbootdir=d:\

This returned the error "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.". At which point I found the "dism" commands. Which I ran as follows:
dism /Image:D:\ /cleanup-image /ScanHealth
dism /Image:D:\ /cleanup-image /CheckHealth
dism /Image:D:\ /cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
dism /Image:D:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth

The checkhealth command return that the image is repairable. This is why I ran the restorehealth command.
Unfortunately the restorehealth command returned error: 0x800f081f and stating "The source files could not be found.". I then tried to run the command using the bootable USB image i had as follows (drive E is the USB with the bootable windows install):
dism /Image:D:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /Source:wim:E:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /limitaccess

This returns the exact same error as above (0x800f081f and stating "The source files could not be found."). This message appears consistently between 94.5% - 94.8%.
I am not sure if running this command successfully will correct the issue, but I am not sure what more to try. If someone knows how to correct the source issue using the "dism" command, or has any other ideas, I would really appreciate it. Thanks so much.

Without understand which system resource is not available difficult to suggest a solution.

When you connected the server drive to your laptop, did you boot to that server drive ON your laptop hardware? Note that this action has a high likelihood of failure because ALL the hardware the OS software is expecting is not there. Getting the same error in that situation does not disprove the chance the issue is with your server device hardware.

We managed to solve the issue (0x800f081f "The source files could not be found.").
We determined the reason for receiving this was because the .wim file did not include the files required to repair the corrupted image.
To solve this, we mounted the .wim file (command below) and applied cumulative updates (CUs) for windows server 2019 to that mounted image (command below). Note that the CU will need to be downloaded separately. We downloaded these updates from Microsoft Update Catalog (https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx).
Mount command:
DISM /Mount-image /imagefile:C:\Temp\install.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\Temp\mount

Update/Add Package command:
dism /image:"C:\Temp\mount" /Add-package /PackagePath="<.msu file name here>" /LogPath=C:\Temp\dism.log

Note that the new "dism" command is as follows:
dism /Image:D:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /Source:C:\Temp\mount\Windows

After running the "dism" command above you should be able to interrupt the log (dism.log) and see which (if any) corrupted files were fixed.
Repeat the process of installing new packages and running this "dism" command until you have repaired enough corrupted files to boot onto your server drive. Once you reach this step. Ensure your server PC now as internet, run the latest windows updates then run the following commands:
sfc /scannow
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Assuming that you have internet access, and have updated windows, you should now get a success response from each command and be good to go.
Extra helpful information:
To find the correct CU we used the following two commands to determine what packages were installed on the D drive (server) and the mounted .wim file:
dism /image:D:\ /Get-Packages /Format:table
dism /image:"C:\Temp\mount" /Get-Packages /Format:table

These tables can then we compared to determine what packages differ. This will most likely not highlight all the required CUs, but it is a good starting point.
